# Alterar permissão para modificar arquivos

Tags: c#, winforms, file-permission

Estou criando um aplicação Windows Forms que irá buscar uma planilha Excel e atualizar alguns arquivos DBF de um sistema legado, porem quando executo o sistema eu não consigo atualizar os arquivos DBF devido às permissões da pasta do sistema legado.

Como faço para conseguir a permissão para alterar os arquivos? Nos testes que fiz enquanto criava o sistema estava alterando os mesmos arquivos DBF no desktop e tudo era executado normalmente. Terei de alterar as permissões da pasta dos DBF? Ou o tratamento pode ser feito na aplicação para "ganhar" essas permissões?

Comment: Eu estava com um problema parecido e encontrei a solução neste  


  link http://www.redmondpie.com/applying-permissions-on-any-windows-folder-using-c/

Comment: A solução no link do Robss70 resolveu meu problema, só alterei para não depender de um combo e retornar o usuário Administrador